# App to lock files from being changed

Tags: windows, windows-10

I have a problem when altering a file for a software it changes it back. When I alter the file and start the software it's a success. But I noticed that when I close the software and next time I start it the changes I did and worked last time are gone.

After some testing I found that the program aromatically renames and recreates the file I've altered after I close it since it does not seem to like it. But it works exactly as I want so I wanna prevent it from changing the name.

I have tried changing the rights to block modification for all users but that worked for a short time but not anymore for some reason...

How can I really lock files? There must be an app for that

Comment: Change the file ownership, e.g. to *TrustedInstaller*, but allow the app to read the file. See https://www.windowscentral.com/how-restore-trustedinstaller-owner-system-files-windows-10